# WPF WebBrowser not render external html content properly

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

In WPF application the `WebBrowser` control doesn't render external html url properly.
While source assigned with external url, page get loaded.
But html hover effects & svg animations are not working.
Stuck at this point (VisualStudio 2015 environment).
Help me to step up.

Thanks in advance.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <WebBrowser Source="https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-pie-chart/" 
                OverridesDefaultStyle="False" MaxHeight="500"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: To keep up with the development of web technology, I think switching to WebView2 would be an option. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf

Comment: Webview2 is not support in VisualStudio 2015 environment. While use it, blank page only shows instead load html page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can not modify the HTML content of the web page.

You can use the following trick instead:

In registry:

Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION for 64-bit or 32-bit only machines.

Create a new DWORD key, and name it the name of your application e.g. "myapp.exe" and then edit the value of the key. There are many different values you can add depending on the IE version you want to emulate. I entered 11001 (as a decimal value - 0x2AF9 in HEX) which emulates IE 11 (many more values located at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation).

Comment: Thanks for your response Omar. I will try it and let you know soon.

Comment: instruction followed, but still html contents hovering effects are not working.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: If you could change the HTML file:

HTML fix;

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
    ... other headers
  </head>

Comment: Already i have updated it in html page. Page gets loaded fine with "Chart". But while hover on the chart, animations are not working.

Comment: Anyhow thanks omar, i fixed it by using cefsharp(with VS2019) browser... it helps me to include html design.